# SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel application and now I added notifications. In the notification data column I have repliedTime, thread_id and message_id (`{"repliedTime":"2020-08-15T16:19:07.594839Z","thread_id":"33","message_id":"229"}`).

I get the notification thread_id in Controller using `'data->thread_id'`(Ex: `$notification = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->where('data->thread_id', $thread->id)->get();`)

It is working locally, but on heroku it throws me this error: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown.

Any idea in how can I rewrite `where('data->thread_id', $thread->id)` that will also work on Heroku?

Thank you,
Rares

Comment: Hi @omr, thank you for your answear. It throw Column not found using data.thread_id.. :(

Comment: what is your db type on server?

Comment: postgresql on server and mysql locally

Comment: please try: whereRaw( "data-> 'thread_id'={ $thread->id}")

Comment: It throw 'Syntax error or access violation'..

Comment: Add this into your model `public $keyType = 'string';` and try

Comment: It works locally now using "data->'$.thread_id' = '$thread->id'", but on heroku still not working..

Comment: You need to check for proper type casting